# possible to use YARD to document erb templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, yard

Is it possible to use YARD to document templates or does it require classes in files? I have tried running

yard doc controllers/ models/ views/index/

but the index views aren't picked up. I see the meta data to be added to extra files in the docs but obviously don't want to render the yard comments. I just want to document the partials used in each view.

thx

Answer (score 1):

Use `yardoc --files FILE1,FILE2,...` to specify the file templates.